# Any information about the default ScrollViewer for apps with DependencyObject as a parent?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, winui-3

#### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestApp3
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TestButton_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
        {
            var old = args.OldFocusedElement;
            Debug.WriteLine(old?.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    x:Class="TestApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="_testButton"
                Content="TestButton"
                GettingFocus="TestButton_GettingFocus"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: 1]

In this app, click the free space on the Grid and press the Button to Microsoft.UI.The Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer is output and its parent is Microsoft.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject.

I've looked at the various properties of this, but I don't know where it came from. Is there any relevant information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be the `RootScrollViewer`. You can see it using the [Live Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2022).

There's not much info about it, generally speaking you don't need to know much about it, but at least now you know where that `ScrollViewer` comes from.

Comment: I added a live visual tree to my question. I don't think I can see it in the live visual tree. The reason to find this is to lose focus on the override function of the class that inherited the control.

Comment: At the top of the **Live Visual Tree**, there should be a "Show Just My XAML" button. Toggle it and see if you can see the ``ScrollViewer``.